# Detect Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i have a json that may return something like this

```
"coordinates":
  [
    [[100.0,0.0],[101.0,0.0],[101.0,1.0],[100.0,1.0],[100.0,0.0]],
    [[100.2,0.2],[100.8,0.2],[100.8,0.8],[100.2,0.8],[100.2,0.2]]
  ]
```

Which will appear as an array of array Which I need to handle differently than something that may look like

```
"coordinates":[30.0,10.0]
```

But I was doing different actions based on the length of the coordinates array which in both cases is 2. (2 is a point else polygon or polyline) But I need to make sure that it isn't an array of arrays

Comment: Two pass deserializing, maybe?  Try to deserialize to an array of arrays and if that fails (because it's not that format) try the "normal" deserialization.

Comment: Note that this is an array of arrays of arrays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
if (Array.isArray(coordinates)) {
  // is an array
  if (Array.isArray(coordinates[0])) {
    // is an array of array
    // process polyline
  } else {
    // process point
  }
}
```

Comment: You point in the right direction. `Array.isArray()` is right. But you have to check every element in the array.

Comment: @ThomasJunk Why would you? It's probably safe to assume that if the first item in the array is an array, then it's not point coordinates.

Comment: @plalx »It's probably safe to assume« d'accord. It depends on the source of the JSON and your knowledge about it. In some or maybe all cases you are right ;)

Comment: @ThomasJunk, as we are dealing with geometry, I assumed input would be consistent (either some path generators or user actions producing these coordinates). So IMO, a simple check would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

> But I need to make sure that it isn't an array of arrays

What about a simple *check*-Function:

```
var a1=[1,2,3,4];
var a2=[[1],[2]];

function checkArrayOfArrays(a){
    return a.every(function(x){ return Array.isArray(x); });
}

console.log(checkArrayOfArrays(a1));
console.log(checkArrayOfArrays(a2));
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/wapifoji/1/edit) to play with.
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) documentation to `Array.prototype.every()`.

Edit: Of course there is the case, that you have a mix-state, which in this case would be recognized as `false`, which isn't always desireable. Then `Array.prototype.some()` comes to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
bar = {"coordinates":[30.0,10.0]}

typeof bar.coordinates[0]
"number"

foo = {"coordinates":
  [
    [[100.0,0.0],[101.0,0.0],[101.0,1.0],[100.0,1.0],[100.0,0.0]],
    [[100.2,0.2],[100.8,0.2],[100.8,0.8],[100.2,0.8],[100.2,0.2]]
  ]}

typeof foo.coordinates[0]
"object"
```

Then you can do:

```
foo = (deserialise your JSON here)
if (typeof foo.coordinates[0] == "object") {
   // handle polyline
}
else {
   // handle poinmt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A function like this:

```
var array = [30, 31, 32];
var nestedarray = [
  [1, 2, 3]
];

function isArray(obj) {
  // Under ES5 you could use obj.isArray
  return toString.call(obj) === "[object Array]";
}

function isNestedArray(a) {
  // Is the thing itself an array?
  // If not, can't be a nested array
  if (!isArray(a)) {
    return false;
  }

  // Is the first element an array?
  if (isArray(a[0])) {
    return true;
  }

  // Otherwise, nope, not a nested array
  return false;
}

console.log(isNestedArray(array));
console.log(isNestedArray(nestedarray));
console.log(isNestedArray(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you simply check whether the item you are processing is an array?

`Array.isArray(coordinates[0]);` would tell if the first item in the `coordinates` array is an array (considering that `coordinates` references the value of the `coordinates` property).

You could also do the opposite and check wheter the first item is a number.

```
function arePointCoords(coords) {
    return Array.isArray(coords) && typeof coords[0] === 'number';
}


arePointCoords([30.0,10.0]); //true
arePointCoords([
    [[100.0,0.0],[101.0,0.0],[101.0,1.0],[100.0,1.0],[100.0,0.0]],
    [[100.2,0.2],[100.8,0.2],[100.8,0.8],[100.2,0.8],[100.2,0.2]]
]); //false
```

Please note that using names closely related to the domain rather than technical terms e.g. `arePointCoords(coords)` rather than `!isArrayOfArrays(coords)` also makes your code easier to understand. However, `arePointCoords` could rely on a more generic function such as `isArrayOfArrays` internally.